# NestMember requires ASM7

Tags: android, gradle, java-11, gradlew, android-12

After update to `Java 11` got an error in Android Studio by `./gradlew lintFooDebug` command.

```
* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ‘foo:syncDebugLibJars'.
> NestMember requires ASM7
```

• Ran `./gradlew dependencyReport`. Fixed all `asm` versions be `7`.

• Searched inside files for asm text -  didn't find any suspicious.

• Added `implementation "org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0"` to all `build.gradle` files. Just in case.

• Ran `./gradlew lintFooDebug --scan` with `scan` flag to get detailed info:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: NestMember requires ASM7    
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitNestMember(ClassVisitor.java:251)    
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:663)   
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:394)   
        at com.android.builder.packaging.TypedefRemover.rewriteOuterClass(TypedefRemover.java:239)  
        at com.android.builder.packaging.TypedefRemover.filter(TypedefRemover.java:139) 
        at com.android.builder.packaging.JarFlinger.addDirectory(JarFlinger.java:107)   
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.LibraryAarJarsTask$Companion.mergeInputsToLocation(LibraryAarJarsTask.kt:251)    
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.LibraryAarJarsTask$Companion.mergeInputs(LibraryAarJarsTask.kt:166)  
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.LibraryAarJarsTask.doTaskAction(LibraryAarJarsTask.kt:120)   
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:63) 
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)    
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask.taskAction(NonIncrementalTask.kt:94)  
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1778.invoke(Unknown Source)  
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)   
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)   
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58) 
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)   
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)   
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:498)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153) 
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)  
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)  
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71) 
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)  
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:483)    
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:466)   
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:105)   
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:270) 
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:248)    
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:83) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:37)  
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)  
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:47)  
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153) 
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)  
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62) 
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)   
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:47) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:37) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:50) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:54)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:35)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:174)  
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:74)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:45)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:40) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:29) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:99)    
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)  
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:84)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:41)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)    
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)    
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:91) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:78) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:49) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:105)  
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:50)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)    
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:32) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)  
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:43)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:31)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)    
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution$2.withWorkspace(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:283)    
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27) 
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:49)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:35)   
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)  
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)   
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)  
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)    
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)   
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)   
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57) 
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)   
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)   
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)   
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)  
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)  
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153) 
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)  
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62) 
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)   
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76) 
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52) 
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)   
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:408)   
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:395)   
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:388)  
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:374)  
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)  
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)   
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)   
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)   
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)   
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)    
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
```

Maybe you have some ideas how to fix it?

Comment: The ASM library is up to date. The software using ASM is not. In this stack trace, it’s the classes in the `com.android.builder.packaging` package.

Comment: ASM is interesting, because there's the version of the library and then each software *using* ASM also specifies what version it knows/accepts using [constants like these](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/Opcodes.html#ASM7). So if the software passes in `ASM6` there, then upgrading to a 7.x version of ASM won't change the behaviour. That's because upgrading to ASM7 would also mean implementing additional callbacks and isn't just a drop-in replacement.

Comment: It depends on what the software is doing with ASM. Certain use cases could work with a newer version whereas others, especially involving subclasses of ASM’s classes require the reference version number, to denote whether (not) overriding visitor methods is intentional. Compare with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63408495/2711488)…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an open bug in the AGP that causes this error:

> [TypedefRemover uses ASM5 and is incompatible with JDK 11 sources that require ASM7](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195449882)

The fix will be shipped in AGP 7.1-alpha08 and 7.0.1.

---

**Update 20/08/21:** the fix is already available in
`com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1`

Comment: I am using com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4 but still getting the same issue. Can you please look in to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70246286/android-this-feature-requires-asm7

Answer (score 1):

Recently on my project I have seen a similar error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderProdDebug'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: NestHost requires ASM7
```

We don't use ASM directly in the project and so this is some problem from one of our dependencies.

The project itself has not been updated to JDK11 yet. We have begun to look into it on a separate git branch, but we saw this problem appearing before we started there.

Shortly before hand we had updated kotlin version and some of our other dependency versions.

The workaround solution for us is fairly simple if a tad tiresome after a while.

Selecting the very top entry in the build window which shows `Build: failed` will update the detail window to the right hand side, and this will show a `Run with --stacktrace` option. Selecting this will rebuild our project successfully every time. I'd love to know why this is the case, but haven't had time to investigate thoroughly yet.

[image]

Comment: This answer provides little sense and just repeats the error, doesn't it?

Comment: It also gives a temporary workaround on how I overcame the problem, which may help others who encounter something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the common Java dependency issue (at least not one from the Java project itself), but rather an AGP issue. Therefore you don't have to update Java project dependencies ...but the JVM which Gradle (and the Android Gradle Plugin) runs on. The question doesn't loose a word about the plugin version, which you may be building with... the current version would be: `7.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed after updating to AGP version 7.0.1

Update your build.gradle (project)

```
dependencies {

    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of this error after doing

> Build Clean

> Make Project

Comment: But the error come back again and again, cleaning everytime takes time.
We need spome solid solution here? ANyone found it?

Answer (score 0):

use target sdk 32 then downgrade to 31 if you want

Answer (score 0):

I increased the min API Level to Android 7.0 and worked for me. And make sure Android dependencies are resolved.