# Android This feature requires ASM7

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, java-11

[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68709559/nestmember-requires-asm7?noredirect=1)

I have updated my Android Studio to

```
'Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3'
```

Java is updated from jdk 1.8 to jdk 11

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }


kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
```

I have also upgraded gradle to

`'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'`

Here is my full gradle build file

**Gradle (Module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'io.michaelrocks.paranoid'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {

    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.project"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 13
        versionName "2.0.34"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
                //cppFlags "-pie -fPIE"
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
            returnDefaultValues = true
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/AL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
    ndkVersion '21.0.6113669'

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            // Signing configs
            storeFile file("../keystore/debug.keystore")
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            // Signing configs
            storeFile file("../keystore/release.keystore")
            storePassword 'company1234'
            keyAlias 'company_key'
            keyPassword 'company1234'
            enableV2Signing = true
            enableV3Signing = true
            enableV4Signing = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            applicationVariants.all {
                variant - >
                    renameAPK(variant, applicationName, defaultConfig, 'D')
            }
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all {
                variant - >
                    renameAPK(variant, applicationName, defaultConfig, 'R')
            }
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86"
            }
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "ht"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationId "com.company.project"
            buildConfigField "int", "FlavorCode", "1"
        }
        staging {
            applicationId "com.company.project"
            buildConfigField "int", "FlavorCode", "2"
        }
        prod {
            applicationId "com.company.project"
            buildConfigField "int", "FlavorCode", "3"
        }
    }
}

static def renameAPK(variant, applicationName, defaultConfig, buildType) {
    variant.outputs.each {
        output - >
            def formattedDate = new Date().format('dd-MM-yyyy_HH_mm')
        def fileName = applicationName + "_V" + defaultConfig.versionName + "_" + formattedDate + "_" + variant.flavorName + "_" + buildType + ".apk"
        output.outputFileName = new File(fileName)
    }
}

dependencies {

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////// Testing frameworks //////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Testing frameworks
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.5.13'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.4'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:4.4'
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.10.2"
    testImplementation 'io.mockk:mockk-common:1.10.2'
    testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3'

    // Android Tests
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$rootProject.ext.navigation"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$rootProject.ext.fragment_version"


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////// Normal Frameworks //////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$rootProject.ext.navigation"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$rootProject.ext.navigation"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:$rootProject.ext.navigation"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"


    // Kotlin & JetBrains
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.4.3'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:inline-activity-result-kotlin:1.0.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7-commons:0.10.2'

    //Androidx UI Components
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"

    // ViewModel LifeCycle
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

    //Koin
    implementation "org.koin:koin-core:$rootProject.ext.koin_version"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android:$rootProject.ext.koin_version"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel:$rootProject.ext.koin_version"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-architecture:$rootProject.ext.koin_architecture_version"

    //ok http
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'

    // Room components
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.1'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.4.1'

    // Navigation component
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'

    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')

    // Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-ktx'

    // sdp and ssp for dp and sp values
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

    //permissions helper
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.0'

    //Facebook text encryption
    implementation 'com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.1@aar'

    //Lottie animations
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.2'

    // Location services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'

    implementation 'com.tbuonomo:dotsindicator:4.2'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.11.0'

    implementation "org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0"
}
```

**Gradle (Root/App)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext{
        koin_version = '2.0.1'
        koin_architecture_version = "0.8.2"
        navigation = "2.3.5"
        fragment_version = "1.4.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5'
        classpath 'io.michaelrocks:paranoid-gradle-plugin:0.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

After upgrade, build failed with following exception

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithParanoidForDevDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to read a ClassMirror for com/data/model/response/ParsingHelper$CharSequenceDeserializer

This feature requires ASM7
```

I have tried to fix specifically ParsingHelper class and updated its code to kotlin but then I get the same exception in different classes. So I believe fixing every java class in whole project is not a good idea.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68709559/nestmember-requires-asm7?noredirect=1) thread updating to AGP version 7.0.1 fixes the problem but I am already on a newer version which is 7.0.3.

Comment: Seems to be a bug on Android Studio that reportedly has been fixed as of Dolphin that relates to ASM. Further details can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/fixed-bugs/studio/2021.3.1#android-studio-dolphin-canary-1-2021.3.1.1)

Comment: please update your `build.gradle`

Comment: I have udpated Question and posted Module Gradle also

Answer (score 1):

for me currently the only thing helping is by rebuilding the project each time and then running the app.

Comment: no it does not work even after rebuilding app. I have also tried Invalidate/cache and clean/build many times but it fails with the same exception

Comment: you can try to set java to earlier version in our code base it is set to 1.8 so maybe it may help

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a try by adding `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }`

to `Settings.gradle`

like this code:

> Settings.Gradle

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' } //here you can add this
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
}
}
rootProject.name = "YourAppName"
include ':app'
```

and in `build.gradle (Module)` add this :

```
implementation 'org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0'
```

and build your project again.

Comment: tried its still not working

Comment: can you post your `build.gradle (Module)` file

Answer (score 0):

Add to gradle files the following, clean the project and build again:

`implementation "org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0"`

Comment: already tried its not working